# How do I find an optimum selling point in a time/value series using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a given dataset with value depreciation over time:
[image: value depreciation])

As you can see, the depreciation is not linear and sometimes even negative between two months.

What I am looking for is a way in pandas to calculate the optimal purchase and selling point given a minimum duration. How can I implement that and which methods should I look at?

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you have a `prices` array, and want to keep the product for *exactly* `delta_t` time.

In that case, your gain by buying at a given `date` would be: `prices[date + delta_t] - prices[date]`. To find the best moment to buy, you would calculate that gain for all possible dates and keep the maximum.

In your case, you want to keep the product for *at least* `delta_t`, which means the formula changes a bit: we now want to calculate: `max(prices[date + delta_t: ]) - prices[date]` for each date. Indeed,  we can sell the product anytime we want from `date + delta_t` onward, so we wait for its price to be at its maximum.

---

Now that we understand the idea, let's implement it in pandas.

We start by generating some artificial data :

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "age_in_months": (-176 * np.linspace(0, 130, 130) + 24_000)
        * np.random.normal(loc=1, scale=0.1, size=130)
    }
)
```

[image: Plot of data]

We define the maximum price achieved between a date and the end of the dataset using `cummax`:

```py
df["max_future_val"] = df.age_in_months[::-1].cummax()
```

[image: max_future_val]

We use `df.shift` to compute the difference between the current price (at `date`), and the maximum price that will be reached from `date + delta_t` to the end of the dataset :

```py
delta_t = 20
df["gain"] = df["max_future_val"].shift(-delta_t) - df.age_in_months
```

[image: Gain]

From there, we can easily determine the best gain, which is `best_gain = df["gain"].max()`. We can also use `best_month_buy = df["gain"].argmax()` to retrieve the best month to buy.
The best month to sell is less obvious, as it can have occured at any time between `best_month_buy` and the end.
To find it, we simply try all possibilities: the selling date that lets us achieve a gain of `best_gain` is the right one:

```py
best_month_buy = df["gain"].argmax()
best_gain = df["gain"][best_month_buy]
best_month_sell = (
    (
        (df.age_in_months[best_month_buy + delta_t:] - df.age_in_months[best_month_buy]) == best_gain
    ).argmax() 
    + best_month_buy + delta_t # argmax is taken for [best_month_buy + delta_t:], we need to shift back to the original indexing
)

print(
    f"Buy at month {best_month_buy} and sell at month {best_month_sell} for a gain of {best_gain:.2f}."
)
```

[image: When to buy and sell]

Comment: not sure I can follow. Could you please explain and expand your answer a bit more? For example, why are you taking the cummax() from the end? I think it would be also nice to `best_month_buy` and `best_month_sell` indicated in a second graph, as well as the `best_gain`. I think that would help to get a more intuitive feeling for the problem

Comment: I've added some explanations and graphs that will hopefully help clarify things.

Comment: thanks, that's so much better and very informative. well done!